# How can i create an SQL IF statement to check if fields need updating

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I've created an update procedure that will change the values of a record in a table if the matching record in another table changed, however, how i've got it set up is that even though there is like 12 fields that can be updated, the procedure will update every one of them even if only 1 field has been changed

this is ofcause inefficient, it takes about 50 seconds for just 1 record, not good if there is like a few hundred, i thought up the psudocode for this easy enough

```
if olddata != newdata

    UPDATE!!!

endif
```

thing is that i have little to no experience with if statements in SQL, if i could work with PHP then it would be easy by just running a SELECT with a WHERE clause much like the if statement above then checking the number of rows it returned (if 0 then there is no change) but the procedure has to be just SQL, the best i could come up with is this

```
IF(SELECT o.field FROM originaltbale AS o INNER JOIN updatetable AS u ON o.primarykey = u.primarykey WHERE o.field <> u.field) != 0

     UPDATE!!!

ENDIF
```

but i doubt that'll work cause i'm sure SELECT won't return the number of rows, how can i create an if statement that'll work like this

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features are often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: my work is to sync up a MySQL Database with a Microsoft SQL Server, as you said, different database products have different features, i state SQL instead of MySQL or Transact-SQL so that way i get answers not relating to any particular product but SQL in general, it also means that my finished script should it worked to how i designed will be even more powerful as it's platform independent

Comment: You could always add two tags - one for `MySQL` and another for `SQL Server` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're updating, but you're much better off doing this in a single statement and incorporating your IF into your WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE updatetable u
   SET ... something ...
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM originaltable o WHERE o.primarykey = u.primarykey AND ... )
```

But if you're storing the same field in two tables, are you sure this is the best database design for your tables?

Comment: i'm syncing up 2 different databases, a MySQL Database and a Microsoft SQL Server, the update table is the stating table has data from the other database, apparently the MySQL database is going to used for a web system while the Microsoft SQL Server will be used for in house programs

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know whether a row exists satisfying your criteria, then the `EXISTS` clause can be used.

```
-- If the original table doesn't have a record with the state same as that in updatetable
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT o.field FROM originaltbale AS o INNER JOIN updatetable AS u ON o.primarykey = u.primarykey WHERE o.field <> u.field)
BEGIN

    UPDATE !!!

END
```

Hope this helps.